# The new WordPress 3.1 "Admin Menu" isn't appearing on my site or in the Dashboard

Tags: upgrade, customization, admin-bar

[WordPress 3.1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.1) added the Admin Bar feature, similar to the one used in WordPress.com websites, which appears on both the website and Dashboard for logged in users (if enabled in your User settings).

I've updated to WP 3.1 and enabled both settings for the admin bar ("when viewing site" and "in dashboard"), as well as clearing all caches (through W3 Total Cache) and my browser cache.

Any ideas on why I'm still not seeing the admin bar? I am using a custom theme, but I don't see how that would affect the Dashboard admin bar.

Comment: I'd call that a feature...how can i disable that thing?

Comment: @wyrfel You can turn it off (per user) by going to WordPress User settings and deselecting both options. To disable the feature entirely, you can include the following code in functions.php:

`add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );`

Comment: Ta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

in your footer.php?
It should be right at the bottom before the closing  tag
http://voodoopress.com/2011/02/wordpress-3-1-admin-bar-upgrade-issues/

Comment: I just checked to make sure, I do have the call to wp_footer() in footer.php.

Comment: when you view your source code from within browser, do you see the output for the menu? It's down at the bottom, starts at div id="wpadminbar".  Just wanna make sure it's being blocked, and not 'hidden'

Comment: I do not see a wpadminbar div. There is some wpadminbar CSS at the top of the source (I'm pretty sure this is generated from the WordPress stats plugin, it has the option to include site stats in the admin bar and is inserted at wp_head()).

The site under question is http://www.techerator.com if you would like to analyze the source.

Comment: Wouldn't do me a lot of good, I can't log in, so I shouldn't see the bar!! lol.  Anyway, back to basics.  Have you switched to twentyten to make sure the bar works at all?  Also, ALL plugins inactive to look for a conflict?

Comment: I just switched to twentyten which did not have an effect on the missing WP admin bar. I will start disabling plugins to try to find a conflict - this will take some time :)

Comment: Sure enough - I just disabled a batch of 10 plugins and now the admin bar appeared. I'll report back when I figure out which one was the culprit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: **WPtouch Pro**, a plugin which converts the site to a mobile-friendly format, was the problem and was blocking the Admin Bar on both the back-end and front-end of WordPress. I'll pass this on to the devs, thanks!

Comment: I wrote up a quick fix until the WPtouch plugin is updated: http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/fix-wptouch-pro-plugin-breaks-wordpress-3-1s-admin-bar/